# Apache James server: how to recognise whether a email in the inbox table is a reply of a previous sent email or a new message sent by the user?

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, pop3, james

I am using james server to send and receive emails. 
Consider the case when I sent out an email to a user, the user then replies with a email. This email will be saved into the inbox table of the mail database by james server.

However all emails sent by a user are saved in the inbox table. Im my case I would like to be able to recognise if an email is the reply to the email I sent previously or it is just a new message sent by a user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for the post conditions of [MimeMessage.reply](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#reply-boolean-boolean-). Per the documentation:

> If setAnswered is set, the [ANSWERED flag is set](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getFlags--) in this message.
>
> The "Subject" field is filled in with the original [subject prefixed with "Re:"](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getSubject--)(unless it already starts with "Re:"). The ["In-Reply-To" header is set](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getHeader-java.lang.String-) in the new message if this message has a "Message-Id" header. The current implementation also [sets the "References" header](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getHeader-java.lang.String-) in the new message to include the contents of the "References" header (or, if missing, the "In-Reply-To" header) in this message, plus the contents of the "Message-Id" header of this message, as described in RFC 2822.